# What happens if I don't close things like channels, streams and remote connections?

Tags: java, stream, connection, channel

I'm working on a program using JSch to connect to a remote unix server. I also am connecting to a Hive database with jdbc and a distributed filesystem with Apache Hadoop HDFS API. I have been casually including the close() methods when I see they're available but there's growing frustration about trying to close the channels/connections when using a try/catch/finally block.

What is the actual consequence to leaving a stream, channel, or connection open? Does it affect the remote machine in a negative way? Do all streams automatically close when the program ends?

Comment: you have a memory leak

Comment: I'm used to having memory leaks locally, and I know they're resolved when the process is terminated. Is that similarly true for remote connection? I'm worried about the possible effects on the remote host.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is the actual consequence to leaving a stream, channel, or connection open?

At minimum it consumes resources until those endpoints are closed, which may or may not happen if they should be garbage collected.  That may constitute a resource leak.  In extreme cases, the program could exhaust the resources available to it (e.g. number of simultaneously open files).

Additionally, for output, data you have written to such sinks may remain buffered internally instead of actually being pushed out to the intended destination.

> Does it affect the remote machine in a negative way?

Generally, any kind of persistent connection to a remote service engages system resources on the remote side.  Those resources will normally be freed when the connection is cleanly closed.  If it is *not* cleanly closed, then those resources may remain committed to the connection for an indeterminate time; details depend on the nature and configuration of the services involved.

> Do all streams automatically close when the program ends?

In a low-level sense, yes.  And for connection-oriented network streams, this will normally cause a network-layer closure to be performed that the remote side will see.  However, if there is any relevant sense of an *application-layer* closure, you cannot expect that to be performed.  What effect that might have on the remote system depends, again, on the nature and configuration of the services involved.  Additionally, if you have buffered output pending, it might not be written before the underlying system resource is closed.

Overall, however, when you say

> there's growing frustration about trying to close the channels/connections when using a try/catch/finally block

, I have little sympathy.  The pattern is consistent and fairly easy to understand and implement.  That you perceive it as tedious -- which perhaps it is -- does not give you license to skip managing resources properly.  A great deal of the practice of programming is fairly humdrum.  Good programmers handle all that, consistently and well.  It's part of the job.

Comment: As a note, to combat the frustration for the try/catch/finally block, just make a helper class that has a static method `public static void close(Closeable c)` and do your try-catch-finally in there if you are tired of writing it everytime. I think that @JohnBollinger is right though, programmers have to handle it all the time and it is good practice.

Comment: @john Thanks for the feedback! I'll have to dive into some documentation about how Hadoop handles connections through the Java API. As for managing resources properly: I am NOT a good programmer, so I don't know best practice for managing exceptions and resources. Nor do many of my coworkers, so I need to be able to pass information onto them that helps them understand the need for proper resource management when it comes to our production software.

Comment: @JitterbugChew, if you are writing programs then you should at least *aspire* to being a good programmer.  The take-home message should be this: continue to make sure to close closeable resources when you are done with them, even if doing so is tedious.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Absolutely I will, thanks for your help in understanding this a little better

Answer (score 0):

In practice there are alyways some limits. Connection is kind of resource. Resources are limited. Your app could exhaust all or some of them without extra care.

Say you're connecting to serverX form your app. ServerX can handle only 10 connections. If you forget to close 10 times connection to serverX at 11th time you probably won't connect. This is of course simplification but it describes nature of problem of not closing connections.

> What is the actual consequence to leaving a stream, channel, or connection open?

System you connected is still handling this connection, even if your process is not using it. That means that extra memmory, cpu, sockets and possible other resources are still allocated.

> Does it affect the remote machine in a negative way?

Yes. Remote machine can reject next connection or can slow down for example.

> Do all streams automatically close when the program ends?

It depends on system you cooperate. In your case I would gues that yes, but after some timeout.